# How can I dynamically create only the facebook comments textarea without the actual comments?

Tags: facebook, comments, customization

I want to do the following: I want to integrate the facebook comments widget but I want to customize it. What I want from that widget is only the textarea where the users write their comments, but not the comments.

What I'm trying to achieve is that whenever somebody writes a comment in the Comment textarea that comment is send to facebook and also to a script on my server. I saw that this can be achieved by using events (FB.Event.subscribe('comments.add', )). What I need is to show the comments from my website, not from facebook. I'll use similar style - links Like and Reply will be present. What I need is when somebody clicks a reply on such a comment to generate the FB comments textarea. I looked through their docs but I did not see a way to do it. Anyone had an experience with this?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that you can customize the plugin in other ways but the ones that facebook offer you in the plugin page itself.

More than that, I advise against customizing their plugins since then you'll have to stay up to date with every little change they make so that your changes would still have the desired effect.

What you can do how ever is to create your own plugin for that.
You can use the graph api to add comments yourself to a page, link, what not. And so, what you can do is just put a textarea and when the user submits a new comment save it (if you want/need to) and then make a api request to add the comment to this url (POST):

```
https://graph.facebook.com/LINK_ID/comments
```

with the *message* parameter. You also need to have the publish_stream permission though.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but how can I know from which facebook user should I post the comment? Can you give me a link with an example - I can't seem to find anything. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You'll have to have a facebook app, which users then have to authorize and grant your app the "publish_stream" permission. Then when you publish the comment via the url I gave you, facebook knows which user you're posting for. It's hard to give you a link for an example, since it depends on how you want to implement it. Here are two good starting links: [Facebook for Websites >> Authentication](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/#login) and [Apps on Facebook.com](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas/)